# How to calculate 'square' distance, in steps in 8 directions

Tags: javascript, geometry

Note: I probably could google this problem, but I don't know the right terminology to use.

So I'm working on a square grid where pieces are able to move in 8 directions (i.e. horizontal, vertical or diagonal), and for some decision making processes I need to calculate the "square" distance between spaces. Which is the number of steps it would take to get there in those 8 directions. It would look something like this (colours added for clarity.

[image: square distances]

So far, I've made this attempt to calculate the directions

```
  distance_between(source, target) {
    var x_dist = Math.abs(source.x - target.x);
    var y_dist = Math.abs(source.y - target.y);
    return x_dist + y_dist;
  }
```

This is more of a diamond pattern, the steps it would take to get there in 4 directions (just horizontal or vertical). The result looks like this:

[image: diamond distances]

I feel like there should be a simple way to calculate the square distance, but short of taking repeated steps in that direction, I can't work out what that would be. How can I go about finding the square distance between two spaces?

It might also be useful to know what this kind of distance is called, so I can look for geometry resources on this.

Comment: It's just the greater of `x_dist` or `y_dist` in your current method.

Comment: @pilchard Thank you! I knew there must be a simple soliton. Would you like to add it as an answer so I can mark this solved? The last line in JS would now be `return Math.max(x_dist, y_dist)`

Comment: The term you are looking for is "maximum metric". But you have probably guessed that from the solutions...

Comment: @Drunix Thanks. I hadn't come across the term, which is why I didn't manage to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance that you are looking for will be the greater of `x_dist` or `y_dist` in your current function.

```js
function distance_between(source, target) {
  var x_dist = Math.abs(source.x - target.x);
  var y_dist = Math.abs(source.y - target.y);
  return Math.max(x_dist, y_dist);
}

const
  matrix = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, i) => Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, j) => ({ x: j, y: i }))),
  mapDistancesFrom = (source = { x: 0, y: 0 }) =>
    matrix.map((row) => row.map((col) => distance_between(source, col)));

console.log('Matrix');
matrix.forEach(row => console.log(row.map(({ x, y }) => `(${x},${y})`).join(' ')));

console.log('\nDistances from (3,3)');
mapDistancesFrom({ x: 3, y: 3 }).forEach(row => console.log(row.join(' ')));

console.log('\nDistances from (2,2)');
mapDistancesFrom({ x: 2, y: 2 }).forEach(row => console.log(row.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```